# Jquery to Vanilla Javascript get attribute data

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I'm sorry, i want to ask, i want to change Jquery to Vanilla JS, but i don't understand about jquery and javascript logic

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-edit" data-id="<?= $row->product_id;?>" data-name="<?= $row->product_name;?>">Edit</a>

$(document).ready(function(){

    // get Edit Product
    $('.btn-edit').on('click',function(){
        // get data from button edit
        const id = $(this).data('id');
        const name = $(this).data('name');
        // Set data to Form Edit
        $('.product_id').val(id);
        $('.product_name').val(name);
        // Call Modal Edit
        $('#editModal').modal('show');
    });

});
```

if possible to change jquery to vanilla/ plain javascript or can you tell me reference about this case if you know ? thanks
ps : I'm sorry if wrong, i just joined stack overflow today and my English skills are bad

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm wrong, I just joined stack overflow today and my English skills are bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to get the desired elements and  [Element.getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) to get the custom data attributes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  const btnEdit = document.querySelector(".btn-edit");
  const prodId = document.querySelector(".product_id");
  const prodName = document.querySelector(".product_name")
  const modal = document.querySelector("#editModal");

  btnEdit.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
    const id = evt.target.getAttribute('data-id');
    const name = evt.target.getAttribute('data-name')
    prodId.value = id;
    prodName.value = name;
    modal.classList.add("show") //--> some css class to display the modal
  });
});
```